# Fill remaining space if other element display none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with other 3 divs inside.

```
<div id="buttons">
   <div id="button1"></div>
   <div id="button2"></div>
   <div id="button3"></div> 
</div>
```

The width of the main div (buttons) is 100%. If my 3 buttons are visible the width of each button will be 33%, if 2 are visible will be 50% and if only one so 100% the same of the parent...

I know how to modify this values with javascript... but its possible modify only with javascript the display and css modify the width

[image]

SORRY BY MY ENGLISH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that layout using **table** & table-cell props, OR via **flexbox** (or maybe some other methods, but these ones come in mind atm).

Both these methods have pros & cons, but depending on what you're going with you're layout, these should help you out.

According to http://caniuse.com/, **flexbox** doesnt go to well with older browsers, mainly IE9 and bellow that, check it out: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

As for the **table** trick, it has a much better support with older browsers, http://caniuse.com/#search=table, but it has its own little quirks depending on what you want to accomplish using this.

**Option 1 - Table Trick**:

- set the container to `display: table` & `width: yourwidth;`
- set the children of the container to `display: table-cell`, this rule will make sure theyll stretch *evenly* across their parent
- done.

View **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2kuhhL05/)** or snippet bellow:

```css
/*option 1*/

.buttons {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.buttons > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
/*styling purposes*/

.buttons{
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#button1{
  background: red;
}
#button2{
  background: green;
}
#button3{
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>Table trick</h1>
<div class="buttons">
  <div id="button1">1</div>
  <div id="button2">2</div>
  <div id="button3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div id="button1">1</div>
  <div id="button2">2</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div id="button3">3</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2 - Flexbox**:

- set the container to `display: flex`
- set the childrent to `flex: 1 100%` so that theyll stretch *evenly* across their parent

View **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2kuhhL05/)** or snippet bellow:

```css
.buttons-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.buttons-flex > div {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
/*styling purposes*/

.buttons-flex {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#button4 {
  background: red;
}
#button5 {
  background: green;
}
#button6 {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox trick</h1>
<div class="buttons-flex">
  <div id="button4">1</div>
  <div id="button5">2</div>
  <div id="button6">3</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons-flex">
  <div id="button4">1</div>
  <div id="button5">2</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons-flex">
  <div id="button6">3</div>
</div>
```

Hope this help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS...

```
<style type="text/css">
#buttons
{
    width:100%; 
    display:table;
}

#button1
{
    background:red;
    width:34%;
    display:table-cell;
}
#button2
{
    background:green;
    width:34%;
    display:table-cell;
}
#button3
{
    background:blue;
    width:34%;
    display:table-cell;
}
</style>
```

As the buttons are hidden, the remaining buttons take up the remaining space of the #buttons container.

Think of this as displaying a set of tds in a table